Prove $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_a^{\infty} f(t) dt + o\left(\int_x^{\infty} g(t) dt\right)$ as $x \to \infty$ under certain conditions
I am trying to prove this:
If $f(x), g(x)$ are measurable real functions on $[a, \infty)$ such that $g(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq a$, $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ and $\int_a^{\infty} g(t) dt$ converges, then $\int_a^x f(t)  dt = \int_a^{\infty} f(t)  dt + o\left(\int_x^{\infty} g(t)  dt\right)$ as $x \to \infty$.
My try:
$\int_a^x f(t)  dt = \int_a^{\infty} f(t)dt -\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt $ and try to prove that  $\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt= o(\int_x^{\infty} g(t)dt)$
$f(x)=o(g(x))$ means that $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ or that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists M $ s.t. $ \forall x\ge M$ $|f(t)|\le\epsilon g(x)$
$|\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dx|\le \int_x^{\infty} |f(t)|dx =\int_x^M |f(t)|dx+\int_M^{\infty} |f(t)|dx \le \int_x^M |f(t)|dx+\epsilon\int_M^{\infty} g(t)dx$.... but I am stuck at this point specialy because of that  $\int_M^{\infty} |f(t)|dx$ that is on the way.
Surely teh right hand converges but that is not enough
What should I do?

Source:  https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertsejh/ant20-6.pdf  page 13 problem 6.3 b , hint part
Remark from the person proposing the problem:

From Wikipedia   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations


Something is wrong here. $\int_a^{\infty} f(t)dt$ may not exist under the given conditions.

@geetha290krm   maybe there are some assumptions, look at what I added at the end

Assuming $f$ is locally integrable (integral is finite on any bounded interval), b/c otherwise the result is false (e.g. $a=0$, $f(x) = \frac{{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)}{x}$ and  $g$ can be any nonnegative integrable function). With this added assumption, the condition $f=o(g)$ as $x\to\infty$ implies $f$ is integrable, and all is well-defined.
$$|\int_{a}^x f (t) dt  - \int_a^\infty f dt| = |\int_x^\infty f(t) dt|\le \int_{x}^\infty |f(t)| dt=(*)$$
Next, $f=o(g)$ as $x\to\infty$ implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty}  \underset{h(x)}{\underbrace{\sup_{t\ge x}\frac{|f(t)|}{|g(t)|}}}=0$. So for $x$ large enough
$$(*) \le  h(x) \int_x^\infty |g(t)| dt=o(\int_x^\infty |g(t)|dt).$$

According to wikipedia, (see picture) what you are using is the definition of O, not o. I know o implies O. So I guess you are going from o to O, but then since the converse is not true, one should not be able to go back to o, should we? So I found it strange that you are able to go back, it is like youa re proving the converse

Local integrablility would be implied by the assumption  at the end of my post right? (functions bounded on bounded intervals) which would be stronger?. This problem is  later applied with a=2, would that suffice instead of adding this condition of local ntegrabiity or  functions bounded on bounded intervals?

(applied with a=2 and $g(t)=1/(t log^2t)$


The limit  $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)=0$ which I used  is equivalent to $f=o(g)$. It does not hold if you merely assume $f=O(g)$, so the answer to your first answer is NO. 2. If you assume $f$ is bounded on any interval $[a,M]$, then indeed, the local integrability follows.


and where are you using that $\int_a^{\infty} g(t) dt$ converges?

Why is this true $ h(x) \int_x^\infty |g(t)| dt=o(\int_x^\infty |g(t)|dt).$ ?

and how this implies the thesis since we have an inequality and we look for an equality

$$\frac{ h(x) \int_x^\infty |g(t)| dt}{\int_x^\infty |g(t)| dt} = h(x)\underset{x\to\infty} \to 0,$$ so numerator is little oh of denominator, by definition.

Also: 1. Integrability of $g$ and local integrability of $f$ give you the integrability of $f$; 2.  In order for the expressions in my last comment to make sense you need the integrability of $g$. Otherwise you have $\infty/ \infty$

Ok so we are left with $|\int_x^\infty f(t) dt|\le o(\int_x^\infty |g(t)|dt)$, how does that imply  $\int_x^\infty f(t) dt= o(\int_x^\infty |g(t)|dt)$?
